# Visual Studio debugger crashes on set of a virtual property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, crash

I have 2 classes, `DataDiff` and `SimpleDataDiff`.  `SimpleDataDiff` inherits `DataDiff`. `DataDiff` has two virtual Properties, `SimpleDataDiff` overrides both of them. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

They look like this:

```cs
class DataDiff
{
  public virtual Data Left { get; private set; }
  public virtual Data Right { get; private set; }

  public DataDiff(Data left, Data right)
  {
    Left = left; // Debugger crash
    Right = right;
  }
}
```

```cs
class SimpleDataDiff : DataDiff
{
  public override Data Left
  {
    get { return Left as SimpleData; }
  }

  public override Data Right
  {
    get { return Right as SimpleData; }
  }

  public SimpleDataDiff(SimpleData left, SimpleData right) :
    base(left, right)
  {
  }
}
```

`Data` and `SimpleData` only hold some variables and `SimpleData` inherits `Data`.

Now if I debug a line like `SimpleDataDiff diff = new SimpleDataDiff(left, right);` where left and right are instances of `SimpleData` and step into the constructors until I reach the assignment of the `Left` property in `DataDiff` the debugger crashes.

> The program 'program.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

When I tried changing the property in `Data` to `public Data Left { get; private set; }`and in `SimpleData` to `public new SimpleData Left { get; }` it stopped crashing. That's why I thought it could have somehthing to do with the virtual keyword. Am I missing something obvious here?

Also, if I step over the constructor call, the debugger doesn't crash but if I try to open the `DataDiff` object in the Locals tab of the debugger, it crashes. Can somebody explain to me why this happens?

```
public class Data
{
  public string Shortname { get; set; }
  public uint StartByte { get; set; }   
  public uint ByteLen { get; set; }
}
```

```
class SimpleData : Data
{
  public bool IsHighLowByteOrder { get; set; }
  public uint StartBit{ get; set; }
  public uint BitLen { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post the class definitions of `Data` and `SimpleData`, and the VS version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SimpleDataDiff` derived class, you are overriding the base class properties like so:

```
public override Data Left
{
    get { return Left as SimpleData; }
}
```

This results is a circular resolution attempt, as the debugger tries to resolve the reference when you are stepping through the code. This should really be:

```
public override Data Left
{
    get { return base.Left; } // the 'as SimpleData' is not necessary
}
```

Strangely enough, this does not generate a warning on Visual Studio 2015 (or, apparently, on VS 2013 either). You may want to consider filing an issue with Microsoft.

Comment: If I don't need the `as SimpleData` can't I just get rid of the override alltogether and use the base property ?

Comment: Yes, you can. A common scenario for a derived class is to implement it's own strongly-typed property like `public SimpleData SimpleLeft`, and just return the result of that property in the override of the base class property.